# Mac book pro home button

Tags: macos, mac

I recently have bought a mac book pro and I have noticed there is no home button, and I can't find a hotkey anywhere to make the cursor to the beginning of the line. Am I missing something? Is there a program out there that will help me do this?

This in in the terminal btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a text editor, you can use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to jump to the beginning and end of a line.

The command line is a little bit different. If you're using Bash (the default shell for OS X), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> will do what you want.

Comment: I think you mean Ctrl-A and Ctrl-E in the terminal.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I get for trying to write an answer on my iPhone.

Comment: Most Cocoa applications will also accept the Ctrl-A and Ctrl-E keystrokes.

Answer (score 12):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> = Home

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> = End

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> = Page Up

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> = Page Down

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> = Beginning of Line

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> = End of Line

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> = Top of Document

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> = Bottom of Document

Include <kbd>Shift</kbd> with these combinations to select all text between initial and final position of the cursor.

(Sometime home and top of document get switched around, it depends on program, but generally the above is correct.)

See also: [OS X keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343)

Comment: That doesnt seem to work in the terminal. fn + left just takes me to the top of the buffer.

Comment: Thanks for adding that!! I don't think there is any command to scroll up in terminal :S I just tried in Windows Command Prompt and Power Shell and can not get it to work. I'm to lazy to turn on my linux box for this, but I am pretty much sure it is the same and that you can only do scroll stuff (that I posted above) within any sort of document / entry field other than terminals.

Comment: @Adam Bronte - Hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key as well and it works for most applications.

Comment: The best compromise I've been able to come up with is binding ctrl + command + left/right to move between words

Answer (score 1):

The home button for the mac is <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

For beginning of line: [Command]+[Left arrow]
For end of line: [Command]+[Right arrow]
For top of document: [Command]+[Up arrow]
For bottom of document: [Command]+[Down arrow]

Comment: This has already been mentioned by William Hilsum.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.